# Flipping or rotating nodes in Tikz but not the labels

Tags: circuitikz

[image: M1 and Iout are rotated]

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\draw
(0,0)     node[nmos] (nmos2) {M2}
(nmos2.G) node[nmos, xscale=-1, anchor=G] (nmos1) {M1}
(nmos1.S) -- (nmos2.S) node[sground] {}
(nmos2.D) to[short] ++(0,1)
node[inputarrow,rotate=270] {$i_{OUT}$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the `$i_{OUT}$` and the `inputarrow` into to nodes. Same with the `M1` and the `nos1`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\draw
(0,0)     node[nmos] (nmos2) {M2}
(nmos2.G) node[nmos, xscale=-1, anchor=G] (nmos1) {} node[above left,yshift=0.3cm] at (nmos1) {M1}
(nmos1.S) -- (nmos2.S) node[sground] {}
(nmos2.D) -- ++(0,1)
node[inputarrow, rotate=270] {} node [right,] {$i_{OUT}$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```