# How to flip a Tnigfetd MOSFET in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I can't seem to flip a transistor in Circuitikz:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to [Tnigfetd] (0,2) node[]{NORMAL};
\draw (2,0) to [Tnigfetd, xscale=-1] (2,2) node[]{FLIPPED};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead of flipping the shape about the horizontal axis, it flips where it puts the transistor:

[image]

How can I fix this?

(Other posts to this site have used `xscale=-1` successfully with transistors, e.g. [Flipping or rotating nodes in Tikz but not the labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384479/flipping-or-rotating-nodes-in-tikz-but-not-the-labels))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tnigfetd` is a *path*-type component, not a *node*-type one. So you use `mirror` (perpendicular to the path direction) and `invert` (parallel, although for historical reasons the logic is a bit strange):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to [Tnigfetd] (0,2) node[]{NORMAL};
\draw (2,0) to [Tnigfetd, mirror] (2,2) node[]{FLIPPED};
\draw (4,0) to [Tnigfetd, invert] (4,2) node[]{invert};
\draw (6,0) to [Tnigfetd, mirror, invert] (6,2) node[]{both};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `xscale` and `yscale` with path-type components, they mess with the coordinates (as you saw).

The relevant part of the documentation is here:

[image]

Comment: I can not find `Tnigfetd` in the manual. Do you know where it is described?

Comment: @hpekristiansen it's "4.5.10 Transistor paths", pag. 113 as for now ... it is not named explicitly; path-style transistors are composed by `T` + transistor shape name.

Comment: Aha, I knew there was probably an option to do this, wasn't sure what it was. You might consider mentioning mirror/invert again in the transistors section (since they're not "bipole paths")

Comment: @JasonS yes, maybe adding a phrase or even this example there would be nice. I'll do it in the next release! (https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/653)

Comment: Done, will merge soon: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/654