# Circuitikz: flipping potentiometer with yscale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm trying to flip a potentiometer in `circuitikz` 1.5.4 using the `yscale=` option, as shown in the documentation. What I get is shown in red below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Circuitikz version here is \pgfcircversion{} released on \pgfcircversiondate{}.

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw (0,0)
  to ++(0,2)
  to[potentiometer] ++(2,0)
  to ++(0,-2)
  to ++(-2, 0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[american, color=red]
  \draw (0,0)
  to ++(0,2)
  to[potentiometer, yscale=-1] ++(2,0)
  to ++(0,-2)
  to ++(-2, 0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]``

I need the potentiometer with the wiper arrow below the resistor. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The manual actually states that using `yshift` with negative values may result in bad outcomes. It's use is confined to nodes, as far as I know. Rather, you should use the option `mirror` here. So replace `to[potentiometer, yscale=-1]` by `to[potentiometer, mirror]`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, thanks. I read, "CircuiTikZ will not work correctly with global (in the main circuitikz environment, or in scope environments) negative scale parameters (scale, xscale or yscale),..." to mean that it does work for specific components. But, mirror works great. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you try to use it on a path (`to[potentiometer]`), not on a node, amd this probably results in this strange output. You don't want to flip the path (i.e., its from and to coordinates), only how it is drawn.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659791/38080

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! In `circuitikz`, there exist "node-style components" (as they are called in the `circuitikz` manual), and "path-style components". While node-style componentes are based on Ti*k*Z `\node`s, path-style components are components that are drawn using `to`-paths. The `potentiometer` component is such a path-style component: You use it by typing `to[potentiometer]` between two coordinates or nodes.

Now, although it is possible to flip node-style components using `yscale` with a negative value, this technique cannot be applied on path-style components. If you use, for example, `yscale=-1` on such a path-style component, this will essentailly flip the coordinate where the path ends, but the drawing on the path (in this case the potentiometer symbol) will not be flipped. In the end you won't get the intended result.

Luckily, the package `circuitikz` provides an option that is meant to be used if you want to flip a path-style component, namely the `mirror` option, which you should use in your case:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

Circuitikz version here is \pgfcircversion{} released on \pgfcircversiondate{}.

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw (0,0)
  to ++(0,2)
  to[potentiometer] ++(2,0)
  to ++(0,-2)
  to ++(-2, 0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[american, color=red]
  \draw (0,0)
  to ++(0,2)
  to[potentiometer, mirror] ++(2,0)
  to ++(0,-2)
  to ++(-2, 0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation! +1!

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, I just updated it to make it even clearer.

Comment: Explanation is now even better and clearer :-)

Comment: Yes, I should add something like this in the manual... Nice answer. I have a similar open issue on GitHub....https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/653

Comment: Done, will merge soon https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/654